# Spring RestTemplate GetForObject giving an XML specific exception for a JSON response

Tags: java, json, xml, spring

I'm writing the integration for a couple API service calls; one of those services was simple. A quick `Item item = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Item.class)` where `Item` is just a POJO and everything was mapped right into that object.

The other service is problematic. The call is almost the same: `Attribute[] attribute = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Attribute[].class)` with the difference being that the JSON response has a top level array. Here's the `Attribute` class:

```
@Data public class ItemAttributes {

    private Long id;
    private Attribute[] attributes;

    @Data
    private static class Attribute {
        private String name;
        //a bunch of other fields
    }
}
```

All my digging says the above should work. Instead I get this:

```
 org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read 
document: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: 
ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.; nested exception is java.io.IOException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: 
ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.

at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:224)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:599)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:264)
at com.homedepot.order.gateway.resource.ItemAttributeServiceResource.getItemAttributes(ItemAttributeServiceResource.java:37)
at com.homedepot.order.gateway.resource.ItemAttributeServiceResource.getItemAttributes(ItemAttributeServiceResource.java:32)
at com.homedepot.order.gateway.resource.ItemAttributeServiceResourceTest.testStuffOneItem(ItemAttributeServiceResourceTest.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:821)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1131)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:773)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:623)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:122)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.util.StaxUtil.throwXmlAsIOException(StaxUtil.java:24)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:539)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:29)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:802)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2810)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:221)
... 36 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:596)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._initializeXmlReader(XmlFactory.java:648)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:537)
... 40 more
```

And additional digging has just lead me in circles.  First, that's an XML specific Exception for what I've double-checked is actually a JSON response. Second, even if it *was* XML, RestTemplate should automatically register the correct HttpMessageConverter and mapper. (Right? That's what the documentation says.)

If I use `ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class)` and print `response.getBody().toString()` I get something that looks like this:

```
[{"id":12345678,"attributes":[{"f1":"value1","f2":"value2","f3":"value3"},
{"f1":"value4","f2":"value5","f3":"value6"}]}]
```

I know I could run with that, create an `ObjectMapper` and a parser and grab what I want, but that doesn't address the bigger question of *why* the other approach isn't working, and why it's throwing that exception.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.  Despite assurances from the API team that the response was definitely "application/json" I should have done my due diligence first and checked the Content-Type on the header on the response because it was set to "text/plain".  Once they fixed that the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Two potential issues:
  1) Are you certain that the generic version of RestTemplate.getForObject can accept an array class ?  Passing "Attribute[].class" seems incorrect...
  2) The JSON coming back is not an array, it's a map.  Even if passing an array class to RestTemplate worked, the data coming back is not going to match and the parse will fail.

~NCM